# How to test DoesNotExist exception of MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm using MongoEngine with Flask to develop a REST Api

How can I test the exception of a DoesNotExist?

If I use

```
assertRaises(DoesNotExist, Model.objects.get(id=id))
```

python interpreter raises a NameError exception.

How can I import this DoesNotExist exception?

I've seen some people importing

```
from django.db.models.base import ObjectDoesNotExist
```

but I am using Flask with MongoEngine and need to know from where should I import DoesNotExist

Comment: If you want to catch this exception in a try-catch block use **`Modelname`.DoesNotExist**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just using `assertRaises` incorrectly - function arguments should be passed *alongside* with the function under test:

```
assertRaises(DoesNotExist, Model.objects.get, id=id)
```